# Ansible - Modify multiple lines using lineinfile

Tags: regex, ansible, insert, ansible-2.x

I need to update a Confluent config file.  I need to modify the line, if it satisfies a regex and add, if a line with such a regex doesn't exist

Ansible version 2.9

This is what I have tried.  It updates one line, but adds others at the end if the lines exists

```
- name: Checking for entry to be present if not add entry   
  lineinfile:
    path: "{{test_path}}server.properties"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
  loop:
    - { regexp: 'listeners(\\s)*=(\\s)*SASL_SSL://:9092', line: 'listeners=INTERNAL://:9092' }
    - { regexp: 'inter\\.broker\\.listener\\.name[\s\S]*=[\s\S]*SASL_SSL', line: 'inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL' }
    - { regexp: 'advertised\.listeners[\s\S]*=[\s\S]*(.*)', line: 'advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://{{inventory_hostname}}:9092' }
    - { regexp: 'listener.name.sasl_ssl.plain.sasl.jaas.config', line: 'listener.name.internal.plain.sasl.jaas.config' }
    - { regexp: 'security.inter.broker.protocol[\s\S]*=[\s\S]*SASL_SSL', line: 'listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:SASL_SSL' }
    - { regexp: 'super.users[\s\S]*=[\s\S]*User:broker;User:admin;User:client;', line: 'super.users=User:admin;User:client;User:kafka_connect;User:schema_registry;User:kafka_rest;User:ksql;User:control_center;'}
  register: serverpropsupd
```

For testing, I have tried a couple of them by escaping the special characters in regular expressions and couple of them left as is.

Is it possible to do this in a loop?  How can I use ansible to modify / insert the lines that satisfy the regex?

**UPDATE**

Updated playbook to remove escapes for the regexes, added sample input file and updated output  file

```
- name: Checking for entry to be present if not add entry   
  lineinfile:
    path: "server.props.min"
    regexp: "{{ item.regexp }}"
    state: present
    line: "{{ item.line }}"
  loop:
    - { regexp: 'listeners(\s)*=(\s)*SASL_SSL://:9092', line: 'listeners=INTERNAL://:9092' }
    - { regexp: 'inter.broker.listener.name[\s]*=[\s]*SASL_SSL', line: 'inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL' }
    - { regexp: 'advertised.listeners(\s)*=(\s)*(.*)', line: 'advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://{{inventory_hostname}}:9092' }
    - { regexp: 'listener.name.sasl_ssl.plain.sasl.jaas.config', line: 'listener.name.internal.plain.sasl.jaas.config' }
    - { regexp: 'security.inter.broker.protocol(\s)*=(\s)*SASL_SSL', line: 'listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:SASL_SSL' }
    - { regexp: 'super.users(\s)*=(\s)*User:broker;User:admin;User:client;', line: 'super.users=User:admin;User:client;User:kafka_connect;User:schema_registry;User:kafka_rest;User:ksql;User:control_center;'}
  register: serverpropsupd
```

**Input File**

```
log.dirs = /var/lib/kafka/data
broker.id = 1

ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2
super.users = User:admin;User:client;User:kafka_connect;User:schema_registry;User:kafka_rest;User:ksql;User:control_center;
authorizer.class.name = kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer


listener.security.protocol.map = INTERNAL:SASL_SSL
listeners = INTERNAL://:9092
advertised.listeners = INTERNAL://brksrv1:9092

## Inter Broker Listener Configuration
inter.broker.listener.name = INTERNAL
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms = PLAIN
```

**File after running the playbook**

```
log.dirs = /var/lib/kafka/data
broker.id = 1

ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2
super.users = User:admin;User:client;User:kafka_connect;User:schema_registry;User:kafka_rest;User:ksql;User:control_center;
authorizer.class.name = kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer


listener.security.protocol.map = INTERNAL:SASL_SSL
listeners = INTERNAL://:9092
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://broker1-dev:9092

## Inter Broker Listener Configuration
inter.broker.listener.name = INTERNAL
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms = PLAIN
##### These below lines got added instead of getting replaced
listeners=INTERNAL://:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
listener.name.internal.plain.sasl.jaas.config
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:SASL_SSL
super.users=User:admin;User:client;User:kafka_connect;User:schema_registry;User:kafka_rest;User:ksql;User:control_center;
```

In this situation - I only expect `listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:SASL_SSL` to get added to the file since it doesn't exist and since other lines with the regex do not exist, I don't expect them to get added,

On some severs, the configuration is a little different and the regex lines exist, then I want them to be replaced by the other part.

For example,
If `'listeners(\s)*=(\s)*SASL_SSL://:9092'`  exists, then I want that to be replaced by `'listeners=INTERNAL://:9092'`

I tested the above versions of regex on pythex.org and they found the lines when the regex was satisfied

Please let me know, if this can be done this way or if I should do it with a different approach / module in ansible.

Comment: The use case looks more like a job for the template module for me. That would simplify a lot.

Comment: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/ => `single quotes: 'have ''one'' escape pattern'`, i.e. you don't escape backslashes with backslashes for a regex inside single quotes in yaml.

Comment: Please [edit] your queston and provide an example original test file, show the result of what you get (after fixing the typos in your regexps), describe precisely the difference with what you actually exepect. In shorter words: please provide a [mre].

Comment: I modified the question and added one example, where any line in the file did not satisfy the regex, where I want the replacement line to not be added at the end.   I will add another example, where a line satisfying the the regex exists, where I would like that to be replaced

Comment: I think, I was looking at what I should get, in a wrong way.   I think I need to change my regex and the replacement line.  Can you help me with one example of that, where I check if the line exists, but if values are different, then replace only the value.  i.e.  in this example `    - { regexp: 'listeners(\s)*=(\s)*SASL_SSL://:9092', line: 'listeners=INTERNAL://:9092' }`  if the listeners line exists, then only replace the value part from `SASL_SSL://:9092` to `INTERNAL://:9092` But if the regex key part doesn't even exist, then add it.   Appreciate any pointers as to how I can achieve it.